# Free groups always free on a subset.

Tags: group-theory

This is from Derek Robinson, A Course in the Theory of Groups:

> Let $F$ be a group, $X$ a nonempty set, and $\sigma: X\to F$ a function. Then $F$, or more exactly $(F,\sigma)$, is said to be free on $X$ if to each function $\alpha$ from $X$ to a group $G$ there corresponds a unique homomorphism $\beta: F\to G$ such that $\alpha = \sigma \beta$.
>
> Clearly $F$ is also free on Im $\sigma$, the inclusion map Im $\sigma \to F$ taking the place of $\sigma$.

I cannot understand why $F$ is also free on Im $\sigma$. I tried to prove it but I failed. As data I have there exists $\beta$ such that $\sigma \beta = \alpha$. And I have to prove that there exists $\beta_1$ such that $i \beta_1 = \alpha$, $i$ being the inclusion map $i:$ Im $\sigma\to F$. I also have the composition $X \to$ Im $\sigma \to F$. I mean the composite function $f: X\to F$, where $f= \sigma i$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Please make your question self contained.

Comment: You mean I should erase the quotation?

Answer (score 1):

Note maps are composed left-to-right: $\sigma\beta$ means “$\sigma$ first, $\beta$ second”.

Given $\alpha\colon \sigma(X)\to G$, you get a map $\sigma\alpha\colon X\to G$, hence a morphism $\beta\colon F\to G$ such that $\sigma\beta = \sigma\alpha$.

The claim is that $i\beta=\alpha$. Indeed: given $x\sigma\in X\sigma$, $x\sigma\beta = x\sigma\alpha$. So $(x\sigma)i\beta = (x\sigma)\beta = (x\sigma)\alpha$. Thus, $i\beta=\alpha$, as claimed.

(In short: what you want to show is that the restriction of $\beta$ to $\sigma(X)$ is $\alpha$; but this follows from the definition of $\beta$).

Comment: Thanks. Very clear. A question: for $F$ to be free on $X$ the condition $\alpha=\sigma \beta$ has to be satisfied for every function $\sigma$? Or $F$ is free with respect to the given $\sigma$ only?

Comment: @stf91: $\sigma$ is part of the data defining the free group (note it says “more exactly, $(F,\sigma)$”). So $\sigma$ is **fixed**. It’s just relative to the given $\sigma$ (at least, the definition is).